# Is this an Overflow? - Twos Complement

Tags: binary, decimal, twos-complement

I am trying to add the following two binary numbers together, however I am unable to do so becuase im not sure whether or not this is an overflow?

110101 + 010111
The answer I get is: 1001100

Do I remove the left most 1 in the answer or do I keep it? By removing it I get 12, otherwise the answer is Not right. Am I doing something wrong?

Is this right?

Comment: the end answer is 1001100 which should be (-11) + 23 = 12. - However if I were to remove the left most 1, i get 12 - do i just leave the 1 out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends upon the size of the word in bits of the system you are talking about. In an 8-bit (or higher) system, and you're doing 2's complement, the sum of

```
110101 + 010111 = 1001100
```

Is the same as:

```
00110101 + 00010111 = 01001100
```

Is: `53 + 23 = 76` with no overflow or carry out.

If it's a 7-bit system, doing 2's complement, then you have:

```
0110101 + 0010111 = 1001100
```

Which is `53 + 23 = -52`. There's an overflow, but no carry out.

If it's a 6-bit system, doing  2's complement, then:

```
110101 + 010111 = (1)001100
```

Which is `-11 + 23 = 12`. There's no overflow but there's a carry out. Note that in a 6-bit system you can't have `1001100` technically because it's 7 bits. You would have `001100`.

For reference, see [The CARRY flag and OVERFLOW flag in binary arithmetic](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt).